# Converting data into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I have a node server. It takes ajax calls and uses the data in this format.

> {"action":"login","data":{"uname":"fas4","password":"jaltheband"}}

I am using a local ajax call and converting my username and password in this format but when I console.log req.body, it shows me a strange format. This is how I am converting data in JSON.

```
var data = '{"action":"login","data":{"uname":"'+$("#username").val()+'","password","'+$("#password").val()+'"}}';
```

And then I console.log(req.body), this is displayed.

The formats are different. Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: *Never* create JSON strings manually. Make an object and `JSON.stringify()` it.

Comment: Well, you're creating invalid JSON to begin with `"password","'+$("#password").val()+'` Also why not just create the object then `JSON.stringify` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the "password" key, a double quote followed by colon is missing and the comma is misplaced, try this -

```
var data = '{"action":"login","data":{"uname":"'+$("#username").val()+'","password":"'+$("#password").val()+'"}}';
```